# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list' in numpy intersect1d

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to apply intersect between two list,phone & phone_office.So I wrote following code

```
phone=df_final_naFill.iloc[0,4]
type(phone) # List
s=pd.Series(phone)
type(s) #pandas.core.series.Series
a=pd.Series(s.apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int).groupby(level=0).apply(list))
phone_office=df_final_naFill.iloc[0,6]
# type(phone_office) #List
h=pd.Series(phone_office)
phone_comb=np.intersect1d(a,h)
```

But after running the code, I'm getting following error message

```
  File "<ipython-input-206-3512341621de>", line 1, in <module>
    phone_comb=np.intersect1d(a,h)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 337, in intersect1d
    aux.sort()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

The first 5 rows of phone looks like

```
0    [735015372, 72151508105, 7217511580, 721150431...
1                                                   []
2    [735152771, 7351515043, 7115380870, 7115427...
3    [7111332015, 73140214, 737443075, 7110815115...
4    [718218718, 718221342, 73551401, 71811507...
```

my h looks like

```
      1541291
      1011248
      1015925
      1013535
      1093131
      1125310
      1154955
      1158590
      1103552
      1121881
```

and a looks like

```
[92972897]
[92020181]
[92038083]
[92083771]
[92611383]
[93290963]
[93262309]
[92966917]
[93181110]
[93396990]
[93186911]
[92011329]
```

although type of a & h are showing as pandas.core.series.Series. I'm guessing this type of format for a is coming in some iterations.Most of the time my code is running without any error.

Can you suggest me what changes I need to do in python 3.x?

Comment: Could you show how `a` and `h` look like and what is the expected output?

Comment: I have given the base data from which a & h came.Expected outcome is intersection between these two.Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can any of you please help me to find the solution?

Comment: @tarashypka, added my a & h

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, it works. Yes my data is problematic.In some iterations it works with `a=pd.Series(s.apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int).groupby(l‌​evel=0).apply(list))` & some iteration it doesn't. Will your solution work if my a will have structure like h?

Answer (score 2):

If both `list`s are not nested you can simplify your code a lot:

```
phone_comb=np.intersect1d(phone, phone_office)
```

And if need compare each row in original `DataFrame`:

```
f = lambda x: np.intersect1d(x.iat[4], x.iat[6])
df_final_naFill['inter'] = df_final_naFill.apply(f, axis=1).values.tolist()
```

Comment: The more upvotes you get, the more envy, and so more downvotes... it becomes a problem when they downvote 0 answers so it actually looks very bad (-1).

Comment: @jezrael, Previously you made some changes in my `a=pd.Series(s.apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int).groupby(level=0).apply(list))` and added it in comment section.I'm not seeing that one. Can you please add it?

Comment: @jezrael,can you please suggest some alternative options of my `a=pd.Series(s.apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int).groupby(level=0).apply(list))`. Actually my data is problematic.Using your `phone_comb=np.intersect1d(phone, phone_office)` I'm not getting the desired output.

Comment: Can you still share that code @jezrael which you think was wrong.I think it was working for  me

Comment: @TanviMirza - there is problem I forget it ;) But data are confidental? Because if it does not working I think some data problem.

Comment: Yes data is confidential.I can’t able to share with you.The np.Intersect1d is returning 0 records while I should have some records.But using your previous code I was getting record & it was matching.Can you please try to remember it?

Comment: OK, what is number of rows in dataframe?

Comment: And if create dataframe in pickle `df.to_pickle('file.pkl')` what is size?

Comment: For my current sample .pkl size is 139 MB & maximum count for phone_office is 1544162,minumum 58913.Phone is also in same range

Comment: OK, thanks. Is possible share your data, via wetransfer or something similar?

Comment: @jezrael, No it's not possible to share the data. I have added following line  `b=pd.Series(h.apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int).groupby(level=0).apply(list))` then it is working. But for some series I'm getting error message as  `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'`. Any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: OK, is possible share only columns `4` and `6` ? Data are confidental too?